# Memoize for classes whose init has super() initialization

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, memoization

Here is my implementation of memoize:

cat test.py

```
def _memoize(obj):
    cache = obj.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        key = str(args) + str(kwargs)
        if key not in cache:
            cache[key] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[key]
    return memoizer

@_memoize
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg1
        print "init executed for " + arg1

    def authenticate(self):
        print self.arg

t1 = Test('a')
```

when I run this I get following error:

$python test.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    t1 = Test('a')
  File "test.py", line 9, in memoizer
    cache[key] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 16, in __init__
    super(Test, self).__init__()
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not function
```

Can you please suggest how to solve this error?

Comment: So you always want `Test(x) is Test(y)` to be true when `x == y` (or at least, when `hash(x) == hash(y)`)?

Answer (score 1):

`functools.wraps` is a convenience for a function wrapper, and using the decorator is [like wrapping Test in that function call](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax);

```
Test = _memoize(Test)
```

So, Test is no longer a class, it's a function, and as the error indicates `super` doesn't want a funtion.

I don't understand your intent enough to propose an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Within your memoizer function, you need to create a new type; you're creating and returning a function, and in doing so you're turning your class into a function. An easier way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be to override `__new__`, which lets you intercept calls to the constructor before the object is allocated, so you could do (simplified, but you could replicate your multi-arg handling in this too):

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.x = arg

    _cache = {}
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        if arg not in _cache:
            _cache[arg] = cls(arg)
        return _cache[arg]
```

If you want something more decorator-style, you can look at `__metaclass__`, which allows you to do a similar thing in a way that's more easily shared across classes without inheritance.